# Image 404 Not Found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following error message.

> /storage/images/AiOCjhpQX14cfDq4qxj5AUdWMeAyfelc8RH0rCUw.png (404 not
>   Found)

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    $file = request()->file('image') ? request()->file('image')->store('images', 'public') : null;
    $product = product::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'description' => $request['description'],
        'entityprice' => $request['entityprice'],
        'individualprice' => $request['individualprice'],
        'category_id' => $request['techspec'],
        'is_active' => $request['is_active'],
        'image' => $file,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('products.index', $product);
}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Image</label>
     <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}">
     @if ($errors->has('image'))
         <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong></span>
     @endif
</div>
```

The error I get:

[image: 404 error]

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: my error /storage/images/AiOCjhpQX14cfDq4qxj5AUdWMeAyfelc8RH0rCUw.png (404 not Found)

Comment: Have you check your  /storage/images/AiOCjhpQX14cfDq4qxj5AUdWMeAyfelc8RH0rCUw.png file , is that image file exists in your images folder?

Comment: yes, I have a picture storage/public/images

Comment: The way you set it up now, you need a storage folder inside the public folder, like so:
public/storage/images/<filename>